# p:dataTable with dynamic columns

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dynamic-columns

I will be grateful, if you help me , so thank you in advance.
I'm using PrimeFaces. I have a dynamic database table. I don't have problems with creating this table but I want to view this table using datatable and columns

Here is the part where I add database 's table content in an `ArrayList`:

```
elts = new ArrayList<String>();

try {
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet RS = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM temporaire");
    ResultSetMetaData metadata = RS.getMetaData();
    nombreColonnes = metadata.getColumnCount();

    for (int j = 1; j <= nombreColonnes; j++) {
        cols.add("colonne" + j);
    }

    while (RS.next()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= nombreColonnes; i++) {
            elts.add(RS.getArray(i).toString());
        }
    }
```

and the xhtml code of datatable is :

```
<p:dataTable value="#{templateBean.elts}" var="elts" rowIndexVar="indro"  rows="10"
             paginator="true"
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
             columnsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
    <p:columns value="#{templateBean.cols}" var="cols" columnIndexVar="index">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{cols}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{elts}"/>
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

and the problem is that the datatable i am getting is repeating the same element in each row like this:

```
col1Content | col1Content |col1Content | col1Content 
col2Content |col2Content |col2Content |col2Content 
...
```

Can you please help me where is the problem and what's wrong with my code?
Thank you

Comment: This `#{templateBean.cols}` will be evaluated to the same value on every iteration of `<p:dataTable>`. You need to fetch a different value (an object) from the managed bean based on the row of `<p:dataTable>` being currently iterated over. You may consider a `java.util.Map` for this purpose in which you may pass a key value based on the data table item currently being iterated over to fetch an item associated with that key on every iteration of `<p:dataTable>`.

Comment: You also do not need to use `<f:facet name="header">` in this case to put a caption on each dynamically generated column. Instead, there is a `headerText` property associated with `<p:columns>` such as `<p:columns headerText="#{cols}" .../>`. Also, remove `columnIndexVar`, if it is not needed.

Comment: Also there is no such an attribute of `columnsPerPageTemplate` associated with a `<p:dataTable>`. It is `rowsPerPageTemplate` instead. See also a [relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25658034/1391249).

Comment: thank you , it worked for me by using an ArrayList<Object[]> to store the content of the database table. Thank you for the tips Tiny :)